# Saving reorder of tableview - Ray Wenderlich tutorial

Tags: iphone, tableview

I am trying to modify the tutorial Ray Wenderlich has created at:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1888/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-33
So that I can reorder the tableview and save the new order of the bugs, but I am having trouble getting it to work.

I know I have to use the:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath { };
```

Method, but I am having a hard time figuring out what to do!

I have tried asking the question to Ray directly, but got no answer. If anyone can help me with this, I will be so happy :-)

UPDATE:

I have solved the part where I edit the _bugs array using:

```
NSString *stringToMove = [[_bugs objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain]; 
[_bugs removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row]; 
[_bugs insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row]; 
[stringToMove release];
```

But I am still having trouble renaming the individual files, or what I have to do, to get the _bugs to load in the right order.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what basically are you trying to do?
reload tableview?

Comment: I am trying to reorder the tableview and then save that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to reorder a table view you should first reorder the source of data where it gets populated from, and then reload part or the whole table view. Normally this data is stored within an array, and gets retrieved in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

In the case of the tutorial you mentioned, the array containing the data seems to be `_bugs`. If you look at how he deletes a row, in the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` he first deletes the element in the array, then the row in the table view.

So, to sum up, what you should do when you want to reorder a table view is:

1. Reorder the array: [Here](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/03/how-to-sort-an-array-in-objective-c/) you can see how to achieve that.
2. Call the method `[tableView reloadData]` so the tableView refreshes its data.

I hope this helped you,

cheers

Comment: @Francisco Sevillano Hi Francisco, Thanks for your reply, gets me in the right direction :) But I seem to have trouble reordering the Array. How do I figure out where to inset the row that is moved? Thanks :)

Comment: Would you like to let the user reorder the table view or you would do it programmatically? My answer works for the second case, but if you wanna let the user reorder the bugs, you should take a look at this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW1

Comment: @Francisco Sevillano I am looking for a way to let the user reorder the tableview. I have been trying to implement the Apple Samplecode before, but I am having a hard time getting it to work. But I will try again :) Thanks...

Comment: @Francisco Sevillano Got it working with: `NSString *stringToMove = [[_bugs objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [_bugs removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [_bugs insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [stringToMove release];` But when I force quit the app, and start it again, the tableview reloads the old order :(

Comment: If you want to save data between two different executions of the app, you will have to add persistency support to you application. I suggest you to look at the Core Data Framework in order to do that.

Comment: @Francisco Sevillano Core Data is only to save the model-view-controller design pattern, and not the sorted order of a tableview? Or did I miss someting. Would the solution be to save the _bugs array and load the array into the tableview on startup, instead of loading the individual files as the Bugs tutorial does? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using removeobject and then replacing it again try using this...'

```
[translations exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromindex withObjectAtIndex:toindex];
```